# splitting lists and append them to separate lists

Tags: c#, python, ironpython, grasshopper

I am trying to split a list of 24 objects coming from grasshopper3d,
[poly-lines1][poly-lines2]....[poly-lines24] into 4 parts, so each 6 lists of poly-lines could be appended to different and separate lists- each 6 objects represents faces for a box, so each box which is a seperate list [] has 6 elements in it-, i have been trying to use the itertools library to do that but i am kind of having a problem with function.
i was trying to split the list as well.

```
def split(polyLines,list_i,n):
    list_i.append(polyLines[0:len(polyLines):n])
    print list_i
    return list_i


lists_of_rocks = int(len(polyLines)/6)

for i in range(0,lists_of_rocks):
    list_i = []
    print list_i

    #split(polyLines,list_i,n)
    islice(polyLines,6)

def islice(polyLines,6):
    # islice('ABCDEFG', 2) --> A B
    # islice('ABCDEFG', 2, 4) --> C D
    # islice('ABCDEFG', 2, None) --> C D E F G
    # islice('ABCDEFG', 0, None, 2) --> A C E G
    s = slice(6)
    it = iter(xrange(s.start or 0, s.stop or sys.maxint, s.step or 1))
    nexti = next(it)
    for i, element in enumerate(polyLines):
        if i == nexti:
            yield element
            nexti = next(it)
```

Comment: can you add your input and your desired output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to split a list of 24 objects [...] into 4 parts [...] so each [...] is a seperate list [] has 6 elements

I am answering *that* question. I have no idea how anything else you wrote matters to the question, so if I misunderstood you I will delete my answer.

```
>>> l = range(24)
>>> result = [l[i:i+6] for i in range(0, len(l), 6)]
>>> for x in result: x
... 
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
[12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]
[18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]
```

`l` is your list of 24 arbitrary objects.

Comment: I'm betting that the OP is trying to say that she have a list of lists with a length equal to 24. And she is trying to split them by range of 6 elements and merge the elements into new lists.

Comment: @ChihebNexus hopefully OP leaves a comment.

Comment: You mean the comments within the code ? These comments and the the method `islice()` was copy/paste from the official documentation within its comments. Take a looke [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice).

Comment: @ChihebNexus sorry for not being clear with my question,
the output of lists that you write in your comment is exactly what im looking for 
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
[12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]
[18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]
where each list takes 6 elements or sub-lists 
however could you please elaborate more on this line of the code? 
 -for x in result: x-

Comment: @RashaAlshami: This part `for x in result: x` will run under `Python's interpreter`. If you're using an IDE or a text editor, use `for x in result: print(x)`.

Comment: @RashaAlshami if the question is solved please consider accepting my answer by clicking the green checkmark next to it.